# Change IP Address using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

How can you change your IP Address using visual basic please? I havnt been able to find anything useful anywhere so i was just wondering if I could get some help on here?

Im not onabout the external Ip address. I know that cannot be changed(I have a static one from my isp.) Im onabout changing the internal ipaddress... for example changing from: 192.168.1.150 to 10.0.0.125 –

Thanks
Chris

Comment: .Net not sure you can directly. You could execute the command line. You could use WMI. You do know doing this will give most of your network a fit. If it was me I'd just buy another network card and configure it for the other range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some Windows scripting.  It gets a little messy but you could create the script in VB.Net, write it to your hard drive and then execute it.  When done, you can delete the script.

Here is an example of a script that changes the IP Address (and some other related fields):
http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/40-change-ip-configuration-via-vb-script/

Then, you would execute it in VB.Net by calling

```
Process.Start("<The path of your .vbs file here>")
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP Address is leased to you via your ISP when you go online - you can't just "change it". If your ISP uses Dynamic IP leasing, you can switch off your router/modem for around 5 minutes, and reconnect - at which point you'll receive a new IP.

The only way to replicate this via VB would be to disconnect the user from a modem-based service within your application. But in this case, I'd hazard a guess that clicking the "disconnect" button would be an easier solution for the user.

Comment: Im not onabout the external Ip address. I know that cannot be changed(I have a static one from my isp.)

Im onabout changing the internal ipaddress... for example
changing from: 192.168.1.150 to 10.0.0.125

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, you can do this as standard through Windows (by altering the properties on your TCP/IP connection), but Microsoft typically doesn't allow programs to mess with these settings.

What you could do is have your VB program launch this program itself, and then use appactivate to manually input new settings - but do be aware that some (most) routers don't appreciate you setting your own local IP.. usually, automatically obtaining it is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you may not need to write any script to do this. And you dont need 2 network adapters as the only way to do this. in windows the network adapter can be assigned several IP addresses at the same time.  go into network properties ipv4 tcp/ip settings advanced.  you can put several ip addresses and masks.  so if you have one pc but are using 2 different networks, just put 2 addresses in, then whichever network is connected use it normally.

if you have a network gadget like a new router and its on 192.168.0.200 and you know its going to be set to 10.1.1.x after you login, assign the computer 2 IPs like 192.168.0.100 and then 10.1.1.100.